# 100% Accurate key,value HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

According to the webpage http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_codes_advanced.shtml

> hash codes do not uniquely identify an object. They simply narrow down the choice of matching items, but it is expected that in normal use, there is a good chance that several objects will share the same hash code. When looking for a key in a map or set, the fields of the actual key object must therefore be compared to confirm a match."

First does this mean that keys used in a has map may point to more then one value as well? I assume that it does.

If this is the case. How can I create a "Always Accurate" hashmap or similar key,value object?

My key needs to be String and my value needs to be String as well.. I need around 4,000 to 10,000 key value pairs..

Comment: A map with a String key won't have this problem because the String are constants, so "hello" and "Hello" will return different hash codes. You should do more research and testing for these cases.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That is a little misleading. There are many -- "infinitely" perhaps? -- more different string values than number of (32-bit) hash codes. However, the hash code is only the *first* step in determining if an object exists as a key in the HashMap ... even if there *is* a collision the HashMap will still function correctly as long as `equals` is implemented correctly (and `hashCode` returns a *consistent* value, whatever that may be). I think the poster is worried about too many keys making the HashMap "fail".

Comment: @nathan I think that quote makes more sense if replacing: "... must therefore be compared ..." with "... are compared with equals() ..." (although this shifts the context of the quote some)

Comment: @pst I know that, maybe I sent nathan for the wrong side. Still, to know how a HashMap works, it would be better to read [Map Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: so HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>(); will create an always accurate key,value pair map? I don't need to do anything extra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard hashmap will guarantee unique keys.  A hashcode is not equivalent to a key. It is just a means of quickly reducing the set of possible values down to objects (strings in your case) that have a specific hashcode.

Answer (score 3):

First, let it be noted: Java's HashMaps work. Assuming the hash function is implemented correctly, you'll always get the same value for the same key.

Now, in a hash map, the key's hash code determines the bucket in which the value will be placed (read about hash tables if you're not familiar with the term). The performance of the map depends on how well the hash codes are distributed, and how balanced is the number of values in every bucket. Since you're using `String`, rest assure. HashMap will be "Always Accurate".

Comment: Even if the `hashCode` is implemented *incorrectly* (as long as it does so *consistently* ;-), HashMap might still work as `equals` is the ultimate qualifier...